# Mismatch Dep Signature after Modifications on Android framework

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-source

I modified some code in PackageManagerService.java in Android framework(Android 4.2). After a make, and start the emulator, it report the following error:

```
10-05 08:20:34.213: I/dalvikvm(575): DexOpt: mismatch dep signature for '/system/framework/core.odex'
10-05 08:20:34.213: E/dalvikvm(575): /system/app/PackageInstaller.apk odex has stale dependencies
10-05 08:20:34.213: E/dalvikvm(575): odex source not available -- failing
10-05 08:20:34.223: W/PackageManager(575): StaleDexCacheError when reading apk: /system/app/PackageInstaller.apk
10-05 08:20:34.223: W/PackageManager(575): dalvik.system.StaleDexCacheError: /system/app/PackageInstaller.apk
10-05 08:20:34.223: W/PackageManager(575):  at dalvik.system.DexFile.isDexOptNeeded(Native Method)
10-05 08:20:34.223: W/PackageManager(575):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.performDexOptLI(PackageManagerService.java:3375)
10-05 08:20:34.223: W/PackageManager(575):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.scanPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:3960)
10-05 08:20:34.223: W/PackageManager(575):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.scanPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:3238)
10-05 08:20:34.223: W/PackageManager(575):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.scanDirLI(PackageManagerService.java:3017)
10-05 08:20:34.223: W/PackageManager(575):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.<init>(PackageManagerService.java:1058)
10-05 08:20:34.223: W/PackageManager(575):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:837)
10-05 08:20:34.223: W/PackageManager(575):  at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:177)
```

If I clean and then make the full project again, it works ok. But it will report the same error after another modification. Since making a full build again will last a very long time, I prefer other solution.

I noticed the code in DexPrepare.cpp:

```
if (memcmp(signature, ptr, kSHA1DigestLen) != 0) {  
    LOGI("DexOpt: mismatch dep signature for '%s'", cacheFileName);  
    goto bail;  
}
```

If I remove these lines of code, it will work. I used to work on Android 2.3, and there are still a signature checking in Android 2.3(Gingerbread), but after modifications on Gingerbread's framework, it will never report such errors. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this by running the `make droidcore` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that during the build and flash of your custom ROM you do not clean data and cache images. In this case in these images the old version of `odexed core.jar` is stored and during the boot Android tries to compare the new version with the old one. And so as you have done some modifications the signatures are different.